# why isn't this expression finding whitespace after the date?

Tags: sed

I'm using `sed` to find any expression that matches a date in the format 00/00/0000 with any amount of whitespace after and simply replace it with the letter h. I made the expression:

```
sed -E 's/[[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][[:space:]]]/h/g' dates-input.txt
```

but is not working.

Comment: Firstly try to use other separator than `/` or escape it. Secondary there is no need to add extra brackets `[]`. Thirdly use multiplicators. `sed -E 's|([0-9]{2}/){2}[0-9]{4}[[:space:]]|h|g'`

Comment: What is **the** format `00/00/0000`? DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY? Are you really going to accept 44/55/2015 as a date?

Answer (score 2):

A few problems here:

- The slashes (`/`) within your expression must be escaped.
- The outermost brackets should be parentheses or be omitted altogether.
- If you want any amount of space allowed and replaced, the expression should be `[[:space:]]*`, rather than just `[[:space:]]`.

Try this:

```
's/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][[:space:]]*/h/g'
```

Comment: Actually, the textual slashes _were_ escaped; it just wasn't visible because the command wasn't formatted as code.